# Scraping data from webpage where table related tags are not found

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract "COVID-19 Statewise Status" data from the URL [India Covid 19 cases](https://www.mygov.in/covid-19/). Though the page shows the data in tabular form, I don't think there is a table directly embedded. I am not finding `<table>, <tr>, <td>` etc., headers

Can someone help me with how to extract the table data?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.mygov.in/covid-19/'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
type(soup)
title = soup.title
print(title)

<title>#IndiaFightsCorona COVID-19 in India, Corona Virus Tracker | mygov.in </title>

text = soup.get_text()
print(soup.text)    

#IndiaFightsCorona COVID-19 in India, Corona Virus Tracker | mygov.in 

@import url("//www.mygov.in/modules/system/system.base.css?qfdcj4");
@import url("//www.mygov.in/modules/system/system.menus.css?qfdcj4");
@import url("//www.mygov.in/modules/system/system.messages.css?qfdcj4");

tables= soup.find_all('table')
print(tables)

[]

rows= soup.find_all('tr')
print(rows[:10])

[]
```

I want to extract the data from the table that appears by clicking the '+' button that is at the end of 'COVID-19 Statewise Status' header shown in the pictures below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What information do you want to get from the page? I see no tables there

Comment: @Andrej, Please see the additional info added to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding from your post is that you have to **scrape** the data of **Covid19** state wise which is available in the table.

Try below approach using python - [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests.

1. First i have checked that is there any API URL/call is exposed which is giving data in JSON format which can be consumed for the purpose of extracting the desired data and it is available. [API CALL URL](https://www.mygov.in/sites/default/files/covid/covid_state_counts_ver1.json)
2. After fetching the URL i made a request to this API and in response i got all the data in JSON format.
3. Finally i looped through the data which is needed and important for ex- Confirmed Cases, Active Case, Deaths and Recovered and their corresponding differences state wise. You can fetch other details in the same way like Covid facilites information, Epass URLs etc.

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def scrape_covid19_india_stats():

URL = 'https://www.mygov.in/sites/default/files/covid/covid_state_counts_ver1.json'

json_data = requests.get(URL,verify=False).json()

for state_wise in json_data['Name of State / UT']:
    print('-'*100)
    print('State : ' + json_data['Name of State / UT'][state_wise] + ' , ' +
          'Total Confirmed Cases : ' + str(json_data['Total Confirmed cases'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Active Cases : ' + str(json_data['Active'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Recovered/Discharged/Migrated: ' + str(json_data['Cured/Discharged/Migrated'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Deceased : ' + str(json_data['Death'][state_wise]) + ' , ' + 
          'Diff. Confirmed Cases : ' + str(json_data['diff_confirmed_covid_cases'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Diff. Active Cases : ' + str(json_data['diff_active_covid_cases'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Diff. Cured Cases : ' + str(json_data['diff_cured_discharged'][state_wise]) + ' , ' +
          'Diff. Deceased Cases : ' + str(json_data['diff_death'][state_wise]))
    print('-'*100)

scrape_covid19_india_stats()
```

Comment: Thanks that works. However, I want to extract data from the table that appears when we press '+' button at the end of the 'COVID-19 Statewise Status' header in the page. I am adding the pics in the original question for clarity.

Comment: @Srinivas this script is extracting the table data only. If you run and match the values of all the 4 KPIs you will get to know the exact details.Let me know if you still have any doubts

Comment: If the above solution working for you then please up vote and accept it - Thanks

Comment: yes.. but I see the headers are different. The jason_data fields that you have mapped to names in the code are different from what appear in the webpage. I can rename the json fields in your code as per webpage, but then I want them directly from webpage. Hope you understand what I am trying to convey.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the headers  are name are same or different because HTML table headers are just for presentation and reading. If you will change the name of the JSON fields you will not get any result but some errors. Look at the text which i have mentioned in print statements it is just show you that i'm fetching this specific information regardless of the name of my column/header. Also this is not impacting the originality of data. If you run and match the values with the website you will find them same.

Comment: The API call is also from website and 100% same , so there is no difference between the table data which you are seeing on the website and the which this script is fetching. Just for you information they are also using this API call to map the data to the HTML table.

Comment: data is the same. I am sorry if I am mis-communicating. I am referring to the columns names in the web page. never mind. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.:)

Comment: @Vin how to get the Json url for "COVID-19 Statewise Vaccine" in the same portal ? Kindly help (https://www.mygov.in/covid-19)